# Creating a subclass of int, unexpected behaviour with json.dumps()

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create a subclass of `int` that prints as a string but can still be used as a math variable.

This is what I have so far:

```
class xint(int):

    def __new__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        return super(xint, self).__new__(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"'{self.value}'"
    __repr__ = __str__

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other
```

Using this I can do:

```
x = xint(2)
x = [x]
print(x)
>> ['2']
```

And this is the behaviour I want. But the problem I have is that if I try to convert this list into a JSON string then instead of `['2']` I get `[0]`.

```
import json

x = xint(2)
x = [x]
x = json.dumps(x)
print(x)
>> [0]
```

Is there some method I'm missing in order to fix this in addition to `__repr__` and `__str__`?

Comment: Using single quotes like that would be invalid JSON, so the `json` module would never produce it.

Comment: You need to save the original value in the `int` object. You don't need to use `__new__`, `__str__` and `__eq__`: it will work fine if you don't override these methods. Why do you need to save the value in `self.value` instead of `int` internals?

Comment: First, that `__new__` makes no sense. Second, `json.dumps` will never use your `__str__` or `__repr__`. It makes JSON, and allowing you to put arbitrary possibly-non-JSON text in its output would defeat the point.

Comment: @VisioN Thanks for your comment. Are you able to post an answer that shows what you mean? I wasn't sure how to use the `int` internals.

Comment: The reason `json` doesn't use your string representation is because it's not asking the object for a representation or a printable string, it's reading it's type and value, concluding it's an integer, and creating the current integer representation. The reason it's showing a 0 and not a 2, is because you're shadowing the normal behaviour of `int` with a defective `__new__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example fixes your mistakes, but it doesn't solve your problem:

```
import json


class Xint(int):
    def __str__(self):
        return f"'{int(self)}'"

    # I'm leaving this in, but I think it's wrong
    # a representation like f'Xint({int(self)})' would be better
    __repr__ = __str__


x = Xint(2)
y = [x]
print(x, y)
print(json.dumps(y))
```

Result:

```
'2' ['2']
[2]
```

Note how the `json.dumps()` now correctly shows your `2`. But it still doesn't show the quotes like the `print()` does. This is because `json` recognises the type of the variable it is asked to dump and it's just an `int`.

If you need this, you'd need to convince `json` it's really just a string, or some type that `json` would add to the dump as a string. But that will break pretty much every other use you may have in mind for your type.

I think the real problem is an XY problem here. Instead of asking how to make your solution work, perhaps you can share what problem you were trying to solve with the new type to begin with?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without calling `int(self)`? Does the `int` class that it's inheriting from have something like a `self.value` internal variable?

Comment: If it did, what type would you expect it to have? And would you expect that type to also have a `.value` internal variable? I'm not being facetious - `int` is a simple built-in type, at some point that's what you end up with. The reason to use `int(self)` here is because it is being used in a position where its string value is required - you want `int`s __str__ to be called, otherwise you end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying now. I'm just trying to avoid calling `int` and creating a new object for the new `__str__` function, which surely takes more processor power than accessing the value of the existing object that must be stored somewhere. But anyway I've worked it out and now I'm calling the inherited `__int__` function instead of needing to set a `self.value`.